# Concatenating and splitting returns ubound(array) + 1 items

Tags: loops, vbscript, split

I'm trying to understand where I'm going wrong here. The following script will always return an empty item in the array at the end. Why? I don't think it's a problem with the recordset. Any ideas?

```
function allServers 
    Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

    Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

    strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"
    strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(operatingsystem=*server*)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
    strAttributes = "name,distinguishedname,dnshostname"
    strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
    dim strList, i
    Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
        strList = strList & adoRecordSet.Fields("name").Value & ","
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
    loop
    adoRecordset.Close
    adoConnection.Close

    arr = split(strList, ",",-1,1)
    allServers = arr
end function

arr = allservers
For i = 0 to UBound(arr)
    wscript.echo  i & ":" & arr(i)
next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop:

```
Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
    strList = strList & adoRecordSet.Fields("name").Value & ","
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
loop
```

puts a last/trailing/terminating "," at the end of strList. Split() treats the "," as separator (not terminator), so the resulting array has a spurious last empty element.

To avoid that, you can concatenate `"," & value` in the loop and zap the preceding "," using Mid(). But why not use "SELECT COUNT", or Recordset.Count to dimension an array before the loop and assign the values to its elements, or - even better - Recordset.GetRows() to get an (albeit 2 dim) array directly -> no concat, no split, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I chose to assign the value in a loop. It looks like the 
Active Directory Provider doesn't support .Count.